# Html and Hmtl5 Video

Tags: html, css, video

I have my video playing in the background but how do I add images over the video? I kind of want it like this [image over video](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ju73p.jpg)[My video](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pfreg.jpg)

```css
body, html {
    margin: 0;
    padding:0;
}
video{
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    min-width: 100%;
    min-height: 100%;
    width: auto;
    height: auto;
    z-index: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="container" >
    <video poster="Sample.jpg" autoplay="true" loop id="video">
        <source src="Burning.mp4" type="video/mp4">
        <source src="Burning.webm" type="video/webm">
    </video>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can always build HTML structure for the images as shown in the images and use the video as background of it using some video player plugin like (http://vodkabears.github.io/vide/).

Answer (score 0):

```css
body, html {
    margin: 0;
    padding:0;}
.container{ width: 70%; background: #000; margin: auto; }
.vid{float: left; width: 100%; }
video{
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    min-width: 100%;
    min-height: 100%;
    width: auto;
    height: auto;
    z-index: -1;
}
```

```html
<div class="container" >
    <video poster="Sample.jpg" autoplay="true" loop id="video">
        <source src="1.mp4" type="video/mp4">
        <source src="1.webm" type="video/webm">
    </video>
    <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/350x150">
</div>
```

container centered and image placed on top of the video